# Scrapy split items after processing by Pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, csv, scrapy, middleware, pipeline

I need split items that I got after processing for a pipeline.

**Problem**

I have to download a group of csv from a website, for this I used the pipeline *FilesPipeline* like suggest [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html). After download csv I need to process that and create new items that will be process for other pipeline.

**Fragments of my code**

settings

```
custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1, 
            'myproj.pipelines.files.PreprocessCSVPipeline': 50, 
            'myproj.pipelines.files.SaveDBPipeline': 300, 


        },
        'FILES_STORE' : os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    }
```

parse

```
def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("In parse method!!!")
        # Property Ownership        
        property_ownership = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Ownership')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Location
        property_location = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Location')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Improvements
        property_improvements = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Improvements')]/@href").extract_first()

        # Property Value
        property_value = response.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Property Value')]/@href").extract_first()

        item = FiledownloadItem()
        item["file_urls"] = [property_ownership, property_location, property_improvements, property_value]

        yield item
```

PreprocessCSVPipeline

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        files = item.get('files')
        files_addr  = {}
        for x in files:
            #process csv ... 

            yield
```

The issue that the documentation for pipeline specifies that process_item must either return a dict with data and not an iterable. There are an [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1915) about it, and at the end they recommend use middleware for that. I reviewed the [architecture](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) and I noted that  middleware works before pipeline, and I use *FilesPipeline* to download csv. So If I use the middleware I have to dowload de csv in the middleware too.

Is it possible solve my problem using *FilesPipeline*? or I need to download the csv the middleware to split my items? 
In the 2nd case how download csv in middleware? maybe using command curl from linux, but I don't like this solution.

Any suggestion is welcome

thanks in advance.